# How to create location shortcut by VBscript or batch?

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I need to create batch or VBScript (for AD use) to create shortcut to desktop only for location. For example shortcuts are to specified files, but I need shortcut to open only server location `\\server\shared folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering it as a Windows machine, I'm proposing this VBScript snippet for you...

```
Dim FileName
FileName = "Shortcut"
Set shortcut = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & + "\" + FileName + ".lnk")
shortcut.Description = "shortcut To a shared folder"
shortcut.TargetPath = "\\server\shared"
shortcut.Save
```

the targetPath can be anything like A folder, file or an executable.